# How do I list the Inbound Port Rules in Azure?

Tags: azure

Is there a way to list the "Inbound port rules" for a virtual machine from the command line (az cli) in Azure ?

I tried `az vm show -n vm-name -g resource-group-name --show-details` but it does not display the required information.

**Edit** : Based on the responses, I feel the need to provide more information :

1. Login to the Azure Portal
2. Navigate over to any virtual machine in your subscription
3. In the left-nav, select `Networking`
4. The rules will be displayed on your right side of the portal. The one I am interested in are `Inbound port rules`
5. These are the manual steps to obtain this information
6. I am looking for the exact same output from the command line using az cli

Comment: Az network nsg -h

Comment: If I go that route, I need to pull the name of the nsg's first. Its gets very complicated.

Comment: you may have multiple NIC attached the VM therefore multiple nsg rules and also rules could be applied at the subnet level. which rules are your trying to pull ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Cli, specify the parameters below and use any custom options that relates to what you need.

az network nsg rule create --name
--nsg-name
--priority
--resource-group
[--access {Allow, Deny}]
[--description]
[--destination-address-prefixes]
[--destination-asgs]
[--destination-port-ranges]
[--direction {Inbound, Outbound}]
[--protocol {*, Ah, Esp, Icmp, Tcp, Udp}]
[--source-address-prefixes]
[--source-asgs]
[--source-port-ranges]
[--subscription]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/nsg/rule?view=azure-cli-latest

You can refer to the link below
if you have any difficulties. Don’t forget to reply to this comment and I will be there to help.